# How to check username and password with the mysql default username and password?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have made a Codeigniter Application Installer for my website. let first see the image.

[image]

When I entered all the values in the input field and click the button called `Run The Installation!`. it will successfully populate the `config/database.php`.

```
'hostname' => '%HOSTNAME%',
'username' => '%USERNAME%',
'password' => '%PASSWORD%',
'database' => '%DATABASE%',
'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
```

the mysql i have installed. the default username is `root` and password is `empty`.
so I want here how can I check the values of the `username` and `password` comes from the input fields with the MySQL default `username` and `password`.
forexample, if the user entered the wrong `username` and `password` in the input fields. then it check those `username` and `password` with the mysql default `username` and `password`and displays error that you entered wrong `username` and `password`.

This is Controller.

```
public function RunInstallation()
    {
        $this->load->helper('path');
         $template = 'application/views/install/db/dbwrite.php';
         $template_path =  set_realpath($template);
         $output_path   = 'application/config/database.php';
         $database_file = file_get_contents($template_path);
         $new  = str_replace("%HOSTNAME%",$_POST['dbhost'],$database_file);
         $new  = str_replace("%USERNAME%",$_POST['username'],$new);
         $new  = str_replace("%PASSWORD%",$_POST['password'],$new);
         $new  = str_replace("%DATABASE%",$_POST['dbname'],$new);
         $handle = fopen($output_path,'w+');
        if(fwrite($handle,$new)) 
            {
                $this->load->view('login');
            } 
    }
```